# document.write() obfuscation of port numbers

Tags: javascript, encryption, ip, port, obfuscation

I came across a site that has IP addresses and ports listed for proxy servers in the format **ip:port**

However, in the page source, I noticed all of the port numbers have some weird obfuscation I've never seen before that looks like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<font class=cls>:<\/font>"+(q7y5u1^j0v2)+(t0g7g7^e5h8)+(q7y5u1^j0v2)+(t0g7g7^e5h8))</script>`

which corresponds to ":8080" -- normally I'll see IPs base64'd, but never something like this. What is it? Obviously it is something Javascript can interpret.

Comment: Its to prevent scraping. Use selenium to get the readable text.

Comment: I gathered that much, but I'm more curious as to what the obfuscation technique is.

Comment: Each letter is put into a variable and then xored with a randomly generated value. Then they concat them all together.